# how to tell if a row contains only one numeric value in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to have a formula in column E return 'TRUE' if there is only one cell containing numeric data in the row, such as the last row in this example (the position of the numeric cell is irrelevant):

---

```
A       B       C       D       E
0.41    0.96    0.54    0.53    FALSE
0.58    FALSE   0.33    0.89    FALSE
0.76    FALSE   0.94    0.45    FALSE
0.57    0.52    FALSE   0.39    FALSE
FALSE   FALSE   0.68    0.29    FALSE
FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   0.42    TRUE
```

---

I think I might be able to do it with a very long if statement: IF(OR(AND(......))), but I would like a cleaner way to do it if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cell E1 and copied down:

```
=COUNT(A1:D1)=1
```